# how to convert a byte to 4 bytes to be used as color in c#?

Tags: c#

I need to convert a byte to 4 bits so it can be used as a color.

```
byte input;

byte r = //the first and second bits of input ;
byte g = //the third and forth bits of input  ;
byte b = //the fifth and sixth bits of input  ;

Color32 output = new Color32(r,g,b);
```

I tried working with bit-wise operators but i am not very good at them .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bitwise operators.

```
byte input = ...;
r = input & 0x3; // bits 0x1 + 0x2
g =( input & 0xc) >> 2; // bits 0x4 + 0x8
b = (input & 0x30) >> 4; //bits 0x10 + 0x20
```

The bitwise operator `&` makes a bitwise and on the input. `>>` shifts a number to the right by the given number of bits.

Or if by "first and second" bit mean the highest two bits, you can get them as follows

```
r = input >> 6;
g = (input >> 4) & 0x3;
b = (input >> 2) & 0x3;
```

Comment: thanks for your help , but can you tell me how to get the content of the last 2 bits as well ?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "last bits" (ie leftmost or rightmost) it's either `input >> 6` or `input & 0x3`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want 11 binary to map to 255 and 00 to map to 0 to get a maximum spread in color values.

You can get that spread by multiplying the 2 bit color value by 85. 00b stays 0, 01b becomes 85, 10b becomes 190 and 11b becomes 255.

So the code would look something like this

```
    byte input = 0xfc;

    var r = ((input & 0xc0) >> 6) * 85;
    var g = ((input & 0x30) >> 4) * 85;
    var b = ((input & 0x0c) >> 2) * 85;

    Console.WriteLine($"{r} {g} {b}");
```